# How to round iOS price format from -0.00 to 0.00?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, nsnumberformatter

My app has calling credit.  When it has ran out, the value final value is sometimes a little below 0 (e.g. `-0.003`).  My code:

```
NSString*           formattedString;
NSNumberFormatter*  numberFormatter;

numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setLocale:((SKProduct*)self.products[0]).priceLocale];

formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(price)];
```

then yields: `-0.00`.  This looks weird on the UI.  How can I correctly round so it will show `0.00` when it goes below zero?

Then, I'm looking for something generic enough that can handle price formats with varying number of fractional digits, and leaves visibly negative values (e.g. `-0.02`) untouched.

Comment: How about a simple `if (value < 0) {value = 0}`?

Comment: @Volker `fabs(3)` would incorrectly make negative numbers positive, though, not just `+-0`!

Comment: @MikeW (-0. < 0) is `false`

Comment: @JasonCoco from the question information the question gives, the behavior of fabs() might not be a problem

Comment: @JasonCoco Possibly, but not before it's rounded.

Comment: @MikeW When a credit turns out as `-0.02` I don't want that to be turned into `0.02` of course. Due to miscalculations this may happen.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html : The rounding behavior methods looks like what you need, but I've never used it myself.

Comment: @Nighthawk441 I tried a few things, but no. Write an answer if you've can find it and I will reward instantly.

Comment: @meaning-matters Have you tried roundingMode kCFNumberFormatterRoundDown when (fabs(value) < 0.01)?

Comment: @Nighthawk441 Yes, results in `-0.00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with:

```
...

double factor = pow(10, numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits);
price = round(price * factor) / factor;
if (fpclassify(price) == FP_ZERO)
{
    price = fabs(price);
}

formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(price)];
```

But I wonder if there's not a nicer/cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

There may be something you can configure on the number formatter, but if there isn't, you can do something like this:

```
if (fpclassify(price) == FP_ZERO)
{
    price = fabs(price);
}
formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(price)];
```

Comment: This solution confuses `float` representation with presentation; does not work.  For example `-0.003` is not `FP_ZERO` and would show up as `-0.00`,

Comment: I did end up using `fpclassify()`, so +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't clean, but it should be reliable.

```
formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(price)];
NSLog(@"Before correction %@", formattedString);

if ([[numberFormatter numberFromString:formattedString] floatValue] == -0.0) {
    formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@0.0];
};
NSLog(@"After correction %@", formattedString);
```

This results in:

```
2014-04-16 15:00:05.887 APP_NAME[32121:60b] Before correction $-0.00
2014-04-16 15:00:05.890 APP_NAME[32121:60b] After correction $0.00
```